# Conditional formatting formula to highlight/color an entire row based on two different column values

Tags: excel

I have searched far and wide but cannot seem to find a question that answers this.

I am trying to highlight/color an entire row in Microsoft Excel for Mac (16.33) based on two different values in two different columns.

This is my current forumla:

```
=AND(SEARCH("no",INDIRECT("C"&ROW())),SEARCH("yes",INDIRECT("D"&ROW())))
```

From my understanding, it is searching first in column C for "No", then proceeding to search column D for "yes". Enclosing this in `AND()` must ensure that both cases are true. If they are not, it returns `false` and does not apply the formatting.

This formula *should* return something like this, which works perfectly with the above example in Google Sheets:

[image: desired-result]

Column D contains a yes, but Column C also contains a no, rendering the entire row yellow.

Since conditional formatting works top to bottom, it moves on to the next rule which is:

```
=SEARCH("yes",INDIRECT("D"&ROW()))
```

Hence, two "yes" return full green across the row.

I cannot get this to work in Excel with the same exact formulas. I have ensured the correct cell range has been selected for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is such a complex formula needed? The following must work in Excel:

```
=($C1="N")*($D1="Y") - for yellow
=($C1="Y")*($D1="Y") - for green
```

[image]

Don't know about GoogleSheets

Comment: Wow. I didn't know I could simplify it that much. Thank you.